# how to use testDescription of the ieee standrad ATML(The version of 2010 demo)

Tags: automated-tests

1. How to describe the plan about monitoring a continuous signal, such as the electric current, by using TestDescription and TestResults of the IEEE standard ATML?
2. My intention is to just use the TestDescription and TestResult as a test description and result description for my system.
   But in the use of TestDescription, for the child elements of the : , its referential constraints are not too clear.
   Such as:

> < td: Operation xsi: type = "td: OperationRead" ID = "" name = "" >
>
> < td: Measurement ID = "" / >
>
> < td: LocalSensorSignalReference localSensorSignalID = "" / >

What is the Measurement ID referred to? And LocalSensorSignalID?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your first question, signals are generally described using IEEE 1641.  They can be described in varying levels of detail, from simple to very complex.

Regarding your second question - the IEEE standards describe all the TestDescription elements and attributes.  Do you have those documents?

Basically, the Measurement element contains measurement info for the OperationRead.  The ID is to identify the measurement for comparison later.  LocalSensorSignalReference is the signal to be measured.  LocalSensorSignalId identifies the signal setup in an OperationSetup element.

May I ask what you are doing with ATML?  I am very interested in ATML and looking for others who are interested.

Comment: I'm also very interested in ATML, maybe we can discuss about it if it's possible.

Comment: I would love to discuss.  HOw can we take the conversation offline?